# React navigation 5 tabBarVisible not completely hidden

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation-v5

I added a button in tabBarIcon and it is not completely hidden when using tabBarVisible,my code:

file: App.js
i'm just added a different icon in AddScreen.

```
import HomeStack from './stacks/Home';
import UserStack from './stacks/User';
import AddStack from './stacks/Add';

import AddIcon from './AddIcon';

const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Home"
          component={HomeStack}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => <IconAnt name={'home'} style={styles.icon} />,
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Add"
          component={AddStack}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => <AddIcon />, // icon add
            title: '',
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="User"
          component={UserStack}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: () => <IconAnt name={'user'} style={styles.icon} />,
          }}
        />
      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

file: stacks/Home.js
when press 'go to detail', I'm hide the tabbar

```
function HomeScreen({navigation}) {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Home!</Text>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Detail')}>
        <Text>go to detail/Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
}

function DetailScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Detail!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const HomeStack = createStackNavigator();
export default function ({navigation, route}) {
  var tabBarVisible = true;
  if (typeof route.state !== 'undefined') {
    const {routes} = route.state;
    if (routes.length > 1) {
      tabBarVisible = false;
    }
  }
  navigation.setOptions({tabBarVisible});
  // tabbar will hide when moving to Detail screen
  return (
    <HomeStack.Navigator>
      <HomeStack.Screen name={'Home'} component={HomeScreen} />
      <HomeStack.Screen name={'Detail'} component={DetailScreen} />
    </HomeStack.Navigator>
  );
}
```

AddIcon.js
file icon of AddScreen

```
export default function () {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.button}>
        <IconAnt name={'plus'} style={{fontSize: 30, color: '#fff'}} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    position: 'absolute',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 99,
  },
  button: {
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    width: 72,
    height: 72,
    borderRadius: 72 / 2,
    backgroundColor: 'red',
    position: 'absolute',
    marginTop: -45,
    shadowColor: 'red',
    shadowRadius: 5,
    shadowOffset: {height: 10},
    shadowOpacity: 0.3,
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderColor: '#FFFFFF',
    zIndex: 99,
  },
});
```

Screenshot:
[Home screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcl6k.png)
[Detail screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rGdaP.png)

How do I hide it completely? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Actually your tab bar is hiding but as you place this on above of the tabs that's why you still able to see after making `tabBarVisible = false` you also have to hide it manually with styles while making `tabBarVisible = false`, Check the route and apply styles dynamically.

pass `style` object to `tabBarOptions`

```
tabBarOptions: {
   style: {
      opacity: 0 
   }
}
```

Or this may also work

```
tabBarOptions: {
   style: {
      top: 50 
   }
}
```

Edit: By looking into your code I had to change some structure of your navigator and now it's working in the snack, You were rendering stack inside the tabs but it should be tabs inside a stack.

[Link to snack](https://snack.expo.io/@waheed25/github.com-phuoctamm-rnavigation)

Comment: Thank u for answer my question, but your way is not work. are u have another way ?

Comment: Could you make a snack on the expo and I will fix it.

Comment: here: [link](https://snack.expo.io/@git/github.com/phuoctamm/RNavigation). thank you so much <3

Comment: sorry I don't usually use expo,I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Have you looked at the snack i shared?

Comment: I have added a link of snack after editing my answer, visit that link and i have fixed your problem on that link and it's working there and also code is there.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced the same issue when I used the custom image.

Here is my solution.

You have to find the index of the Tab you want to hide. Then you can handle the opacity of the tab bar by checking the index.

```
tabBarOptions={{
     style: {...styles.navigator, opacity: routeIndex === 2 ? 0 : 1},
   }}

const HomeTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
export const HomeTabScreens = ({route}) => {
 const routeIndex = route.state.index; // 2 is the screen that I want to hide.
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add focused prop in tabBarIcon and apply style accordingly :

```
tabBarIcon: ({focused) => { 
     <Image
            source={InstaCircleIcon}
            style={[
              {width: 87, height: 87},
              focused && {width: 0, height: 87},
            ]}
          />
}
```

**Complete example**

```
<Tab.Screen
    name="Addpost"
    component={Addpost}
    options={{
      tabBarLabel: '',
      tabBarIcon: ({focused}) => (
        <TouchableOpacity style={[{top: -30, borderRadius: 50}]}>
          <Image
            source={InstaCircleIcon}
            style={[
              {width: 87, height: 87},
              focused && {width: 0, height: 87},
            ]}
          />
        </TouchableOpacity>
      ),

      tabBarVisible: false,
    }}
  />
```

Comment: focused prop only work in case of screen of which icon is causing the issue.
don't know how to make it work for other screen also, if you got the answer please let me know.